# Ordering delegates with various datatypes

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I would like to build a delegate to be used for ordering a collection:

```
 switch(vm.OrderBy){
            case "Title":
                vm.Albums = _albumRepo.Get(a => a.Title);
                break;
            case "Artist":
                vm.Albums = _albumRepo.Get(a => a.Artist.Name);
                break;
            case "Price":
                vm.Albums = _albumRepo.Get(a => a.Price);
                break;
```

My repository method is:

```
public IEnumerable<Album> Get(Func<Album, string> orderingDelegate = null)
    {
        IEnumerable<Album> albums;

        if (orderingDelegate == null)
            albums = _context.Albums.OrderBy(a => a.Title);
        else
            albums = _context.Albums.OrderBy(orderingDelegate);

        return albums;
    }
```

So, I pass a `Func<Album, string>` to my Get() method, which is well and good so long as the ordering property is of type String. However, price is a decimal, so this won't compile:

```
_albumRepo.Get(a => a.Price);
```

Do I need to create another Get method just so I can order with decimals?

```
public IEnumerable<Album> Get(Func<Album, decimal> orderingDelegate = null){ }
```

Or is there a better way to do this?

Thanks!

Chris

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you change the signature to be generic?

```
public IEnumerable<Album> Get<T>(Func<Album, T> orderingDelegate = null)
{
    IEnumerable<Album> albums;

    if (orderingDelegate == null)
        albums = _context.Albums.OrderBy(a => a.Title);
    else
        albums = _context.Albums.OrderBy(orderingDelegate);

    return albums;
}
```

Comment: I can. It's a little awkward when I have to call Get() without a delegate - Get<object>() - but it's certainly a better solution than what I had.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the simple solution:

```
public IEnumerable<Album> Get(Func<Album, object> orderingDelegate)
{
    return _context.Albums.OrderBy(orderingDelegate);
}
```

Comment: Awesome! I have no idea how that works, but I'll take it! Thx.

Comment: I am pretty certain the this won't work with many LINQ providers because of the boxing operation going on. I assume it will throw a runtime exception when used with a property that is a value type (like `int`).